# Return view into an Iframe with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new with MVC and I need to put into an iframe a view which returns the content of a page( styles/css,text/html,images etc) and the view to containt the main menu of the application, from the Index view.

Can anyone help me with this?

The code line which returns the content in the view is :

```
@Html.Raw(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(@Model.Content))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to create controller with action that returns your view.

```
public class MyController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

index view content:

```
@Html.Raw(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(@Model.Content))
```

After that

```
<iframe src="localhost/mycontroller">    
</iframe>
```

Comment: i have that controller named Template and even if i put <iframe src="http://localhost:4784/Template"></iframe> tag after @Html.Raw[..], it doesn't work

Comment: Let's clarify things. Template controller should have one action method that returns view with @Html.Raw[...]. <iframe> tag with src="localhost/Template" should be located in other view.